# SDK for stop-motion mannequin tracking?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, unity-game-engine, sdk

I am looking for a (preferably Unity) SDK that can track a real-life humanoid mannequin with passive trackers at the end of its joints, using ONLY a built-in mobile device camera. From a technical point of view, essentially I want to achieve the same functionality as presented in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyO5FNhoApw

If I could find an SDK that does this or at least does similar stuff, I could build upon that I think. The important part is to avoid using Kinect and only utilize the camera of the mobile device that runs the application.

Do you have any starting points in mind, maybe an SDK that might be helpful to check out?

Thank you so much in advance! T

Comment: Yeah, had that in mind, thanks for your answer! The problem with OpenCV as far as I understood from its documentation is that it does not deliver a solution "as is", and time is short right now.

Comment: Ouch, bad news then, most of the things you'll find probably won't deliver the solution "as is" either :/